# Tesseract ios linker command failed

Tags: ios, xcode, image-processing, ocr, tesseract

I am creating ios app and want to use tesseract.I performed all the instructions given in the below link 
https://github.com/gali8/Tesseract-OCR-iOS/wiki/Installation

but i am getting the error shown in the screenshot[image: Error screenshot]

Can someone please help me with this issue?
Thank you

Comment: Does the library not work for simulators?

Comment: No not even compiled